# Why is WebApplicationInitializer ignored?

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets

I have a Web application (war) built with maven. 
I'm using an old struts application (no choice). I'm refactoring old services with spring annotation using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and a configuration class.

I use JBoss AS 7.0.1.

I need to implement web services in my application. So I'm trying to set `DispatcherServlet` using `WebApplicationInitializer`.

I've tried by implemeting, "WebApplicationInitializer", or extending "AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer", "AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer", but class is not detected and processed once JBoss is started and war is deployed.

How does Jboss to detect this type of class. Do we have to set a declaration somewhere.

sample code of my last try :

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer   {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        String test = "";
        test.toLowerCase();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        String test = "";
        test.toLowerCase();
        return new Class[] {ApplicationContextConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        String test = "";
        test.toLowerCase();
        return new String[] {
                "*.html"
                ,"*.json" };
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try read this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet?

Answer (score 1):

FOUND.

To detect the "WebApplicationInitializer" implementation.
Add the file : /META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
Set this file in a JAR

Set in the full packagge and class name : 
com.xxxxxxx.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

> Spring implements the ServletContainerInitializer through SpringServletContainerInitializer class. Per the Servlet specs, this implementation must be declared in a META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer file of the libraries jar file - Spring declares this in spring-web*.jar jar file and has an entry `org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer`

Comment: In addition I think it's not a friendly use. So I'll prefer the "web.xml " "DispatcherServlet" declaration.

Comment: Sprig already defines this file so you don't need to mess around it with it yourself. So this isn't the solution...